# Animation in Angular 2 with pure CSS

Tags: css, angular, animation

In my application, I have two components communicating with each other with `BehaviorSubject` since they are siblings. I have a `form` and a `card`, `card` can be either `"question"` or `" answer"` and its color changes accordingly.

To change it I use CSS variables. But I also want a "tilting" animation whenever the color changes.
I can't use `angular animation` because the animation is not `data-binded`  related and in my application, the `card` component is nested inside various components that are animated with `"angular animation"` and it's not working anyway.

What I try to do is to bind a class with animation to my card main div but it only triggers when the component loads. What is the correct way to make my `card` tilt whenever its color changes?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahnvtz?file=src/app/card/card.component.html) that describes my issue.

Comment: Please could you put your code into the question as a snippet which we can run - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My question has a stackblitz with a minimal reproducible example in it.

Comment: Hi, yes, and I saw your problem there (which is basically that once an animation is run that's it, CSS doesn't rerun it) but for future it's better to put the code into the question because it makes it easier for people to copy and edit into an answer and also will remain there for people looking later should the outside service fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with Angular animations. Here is your example updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aw3zs3?file=src/app/card/card.component.ts

You just need to provied a state function to handle the transtion trigger.

```
transition((fromState: string, toState: string) => toState != fromState, [
// animations
])
```

And you need to link the animation with the target variable

```
<div class="card" [style]="style" [@cardChange]="card.card">
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works perfect in the stackbltz but there is issues in my app. The `card` is inside an animated div and disappears whenever the animation is triggered. Any chance I can get the same issue with only CSS and class binding?

Comment: @TotoBriac There is no reason for it not to work inside of an animated dev. I think something else could be broken. Could you provied a bigger example?

Comment: I had some issue with the logic of my code, I fixed it and it's working just fine now.